# Better error messages for bulk API calls

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, soap-api

When using the REST Data Event, and posting multiple records to a DE, there is a behaviour which is becoming an issue when designing an integration. If we are posting e.g. 10 records, and 1 of them has data issues like invalid email address, 9 records are processed correctly (so far so good). However the error message is not very informative on, which record was the one with invalid data.

```
{
"message": "Unable to save rows for data extension ID 43e12d47-6d04-e911-9493-78e3b50b7f0c",
"errorcode": 10006,
"documentation": "",
"additionalErrors": [
    {
        "message": "email: The value for column [email] 
is not a valid email address. Parse error [InvalidEmailAddress]",
        "errorcode": 10000,
        "documentation": ""
    }
]
}
```

Hence the integration platform is clueless how to handle this - not knowing which records were updated correctly, and which record should be ignored.

Is there a better way of upserting a number of rows, and receiving more detailed feedback on where to look for the issue? Preferably using REST, but SOAP will also do.